# Is there any way I can set up a Brother HL2030 to print on MacOS Sierra?

Tags: macos, printing

The [brother supported Apple printers site](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/os/macintosh.html) shows the HL2030 model as unsupported on MacOS Sierra. I have tried [Gutenprint](http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/MacOSX.php) which says it supports the HL2030, but it doesn't work, I think due to [this bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/gimp-print/bugs/614/). Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I found that the official driver from the Brother site for the next model up - [the HL2130](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=gb&lang=en&prod=hl2130_all) - worked fine. I don't know why they say they don't support the HL2030, but it seems to print OK so far.

Comment: Obviously this is a macOS question (thank you for helping me in a bind!), but I'd also like to mention that I used a Foomatic/hl1250 on CUPS for awhile with the HL-2030 connected to a Raspberry Pi (it printed most things, but had hickups). This might have been my source, I forgot: openprinting.org/printer/Brother/Brother-HL-2030